# Find Cauchy principal value of the following integral : $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+3}dx$

Tags: integration, closed-form, cauchy-principal-value

Find the principal value of :

$\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+3}dx$

$\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x+1}dx$

Of course [wolfram](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%28e+%5E%28-+x+%5E3%29%29%2F%28x+%2B+3%29+dx+from+-+%5C%5BInfinity%5D+to+%2B+%5C%5BInfinity%5D) doesn't say convergence because problem in point $-3$

Definition of Cauchy principal value is :

$a≤t≤b$

$Pv\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx$

$=\lim_{t\to 0^+}(\int_{[a,c-t]}f(x)dx+\int_{[c+t,b]}f(x)dx)$

But how I applied here?

Is contour integration work here?

Comment: By $R$, do you mean $\Bbb R$?

Comment: There is a second problem, even if the denominator was well behaved at $x=-3$: the numerator explodes as $x\to -\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The principal value is $-\infty$.

You have
$$ P.V.\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+3}dx = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0_+, M\rightarrow\infty} \Big(\int_{-M}^{-3-\epsilon}\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+3}dx + \int_{-3+\epsilon}^M\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+3}dx \Big) = \\
= \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0_+} \Big(\int_{-4}^{-3-\epsilon}\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+3}dx + \int_{-3+\epsilon}^{-2}\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+3}dx \Big) + \\ +\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \Big(\int_{-M}^{-4}\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+3}dx + \int_{-2}^{M}\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+3}dx \Big)$$

You can check that $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0_+}(\dots)$ and $ \lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-2}^{M}\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+3}dx  $ are finite, but $$ \lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-M}^{-4}\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+3}dx = -\infty $$
so in total
$$ P.V.\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+3}dx = -\infty $$

Comment: Thank you very much , if we  have $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x+1}dx$ what do you think about principal value ?

Comment: @EllenEllen Typing $$\text{Integrate[Exp[-x^2]/(x + 1), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]}$$ into Wolfram Mathematica gives value $$P.V.\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x+1}dx= \frac{\pi}{e} {\rm erfi}(1) = \frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{e} \int_0^1 e^{t^2} dt$$
Deriving this result 'by hand' would take more space than suitable in the comments, but you can ask another question.